# Zurb Foundation grid move the last column to left

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, grid-system, zurb-foundation-5

I'm trying to figure out a good way to utilize the grid without hacking it at all.

What I want to do is a three wide grid (aka `small-4` on each) in the top row and then the second row I want the columns to match up but only with two `small-4` elements.

Typically the answer would be to do one `small-4` and then a `small-8` but because the inputs are set to `width: 100%` this will not work for me.

Is there any way to do this out of the box?  I know about offset but that only works for items set to move to the right.

At the moment with two `small-4` divs the right div floats right meaning it doesn't line up with the one above. **I could add an extra `small-4` but I'd like to follow best practices on this.**

Here is **[my code](http://jsfiddle.net/bu2Dw/8/)** so you can see what I mean:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-4 columns">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-4 columns">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-4 columns">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-4 columns">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-4 columns">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Zurb foundation will `float` the last column to the right by default:

```css
[class*="column"]+[class*="column"]:last-child { /* Taken from foundation.css */
  float: right;
}
```

> **[Incomplete Rows](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#incomplete-rows)**
>
> In order to work around browsers' different rounding behaviors,
>   Foundation will float the last column in a row to the right so the
>   edge aligns. [...]

There are couple of methods to override that and move the last column to the left:

### 1. Using `.end` class <sup>(It is buggy in version 5.0.3)</sup>

> [...] If your row doesn't have a count that adds up to 12 columns, you can
>   tag the last column with a class of `end` in order to override that
>   behavior.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-4 columns"> ... </div>
    <div class="small-4 columns end"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Although `.end` is expected to work in version 5.0.3 as well, but it doesn't work properly because another [global `.end` class](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/v5.0.3/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss#L374) will override that. However it is fixed since version 5.1.0.

**[Example (v4.1.6)](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/bu2Dw/32/)** • **[Example (v5.0.3)](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/bu2Dw/30/)** (buggy) • **[Example (v5.1.0)](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/bu2Dw/31/)**

Related issues can be found here:

- https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/4215
- https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/4223
- https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/4183 [FIXED: *by removing global classes*]

If for any reason you're using v5.0.3, there are some alternatives:

### 2. Using `.left` class

One option would be to use [`.left`](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/v5.0.3/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss#L364) [utility class](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/utility-classes.html) on the last column to float it to the left:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/bu2Dw/33/)**  (v5.0.3).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-4 columns"> ... </div>
    <div class="small-4 columns left"> ... </div>
</div>
```

### 3. Overriding the default style

Another option could be to override the default style of Zurb foundation as follows:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/bu2Dw/35/)** (v5.0.3).

```css
.columns.end { float: left !important; }
```

Or something like:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/bu2Dw/34/)** (v5.0.3).

```css
[class*="column"]+[class*="column"]:last-child {
  float: left;
}
```

---

### 4. Using source ordering classes

Generally you could use [`*-pull-#`/`*-push-#` source ordering classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#source-ordering) to move a column to a side.

In this case, you should use `small-pull-4` for the second column at the second row, as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-4 columns"> ... </div>
    <div class="small-4 small-pull-4 columns"> ... </div>
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/bu2Dw/9/)**. *(Using Foundation 5.0.3)*

**Note:** For Foundation 4, you should use `pull-4` class instead. Take a look at the [source ordering](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/components/grid.html) section at the doc. But this will only work on **large displays**.

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/bu2Dw/10/)**.  *(Using Foundation 4.1.6)*

Comment: You're awesome!  Thanks for that and especially for providing the version 4 answer because that's what I'm using.

Comment: Don't mention it :) I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Strange behavior to leave a hole inside the grid. Now additional functions should be written on every grid :( Thank you!

Comment: @Gediminas It seems they have assumed that there would be always 12-columns in each row, therefore they have floated the last column to the right. Also, you could override that by `.columns { float: left !important; }` - **[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bu2Dw/29/)**

Comment: it is like assuming that if car has 5 seats it will carry 5 people always :) Thank you @HashemQolami. Now that is the workaround which solves it beautifully!

Comment: @Gediminas indeed :) I'll update the answer to cover another possible solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

just change the class of the last div (the one going to the right) to "small-4 columns end"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @cpburnz. Please explain. I answered the question, did I not?